# Removing Non Printable characters with windows cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, character

For removing non printable characters of a file on linux i use `tr -cd '\55\137\134\56\40\11\12\15\57-\71\101-\132\141-\172' < test.text > test_temp.text` but what is with the Windows CMD does it support something simlar to linux tr?

Comment: Okay found a workarround, there is a software called "UnixUtils",inside of the files is tr as binary, i yust needed to extract it and can use it like on linux. https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/

Comment: If you can add outside executables to your system, using a UNIX work-alike utility is probably your most direct solution. Many people use http://www.cygwin.com/ which is built by RedHat from the same source code used to build Linux.